# Xamarin.Forms - PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, navigation

i am trying to do is after the user register and they click yes it will go to LoginPage. or else the user click the "Cancel" it will go to registration, please help me guys.. i am newbee in xamarin

```
    void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      string ConnectionString = "Server=10.0.2.2; Port=5432;User Id=postgres; Password=ncf123; Database=Accounting";
            try
            {
                NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("adi na");

            }
            NpgsqlConnection connections = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            connections.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command = connections.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO account(username, password, email, phonenumber) VALUES ( '" + EntryUsername.Text + "', '" + EntryPassword.Text + "','" + EntrEmail.Text + "','" + EntryPhoneNumber.Text + "')";
            try
            {
                NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    EntryUsername.Text = reader[0].ToString();
                    EntryPassword.Text = reader[1].ToString();
                    EntrEmail.Text = reader[2].ToString();
                    EntryPhoneNumber.Text = reader[3].ToString();

                }
            connections.Close();
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                var result = await DisplayAlert("Congratulations", "User Registration Successfull", "Yes", "Cancel");
                if (result)
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
                }
                else
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new registration());
                }

            });

        }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
```

**UPDATE** 
this is my App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new registration();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
    }
}
```

Please help me guys, i am newbee in xamarin and postgresql

Comment: as the error says, you need to use a NavigationPage.  You need to wrap the current page in a NavigationPage, most likely when you assign MainPage in App.xaml.cs

Comment: How mr @Jason ?

Comment: `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new WhateverMyMainPageIsCalled());`

Comment: why Mainpage? can i replace it with LoginPage? but i tried this one already and it doesnt work

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical

Comment: ""LoginPage = new NavigationPage(new loginpage());""" when tried this the error says 'LoginPage' is a type but is use like a variable

Comment: first, please read the docs.  Second, this should happen when you assign MainPage in App.xaml.cs, as I noted in my first comment

Comment: dont get it, sorry

Comment: in `App.xaml.cs` there is a line where you assign `MainPage`.  If you don't understand then please post that code so I can see what you're doing.

Comment: see update mr @Jason

Comment: I specifically asked about `App.xaml.cs`, which you didn't post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207289/discussion-between-kaito-and-jason).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your app.cs change MainPage = new MainPage(); to MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()); 
Where MainPage() is the name of the page that you want to open when you start the app

Comment: var result = await DisplayAlert("Congratulations", "User Registration Successfull", "Yes", "Cancel");
                    if (result)
                    {
                        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

                    } """error MainPage is type but is used like a variable

Comment: i change my app.xaml

Comment: looking at your app.xaml.cs you want it to say MainPage = new NavigationPage(new registration()); everything else looks fine

Comment: yes, after registration that user will choose if he will login, if that person click, then he it will link to loginpage

Comment: so does it work now? Adding that change to your app.xaml.cs should do the trick